# Famous People across time

Tags: riddle, talmud-gemara, tanach

Who was  יוסף גר צדק and who was his famous son and even more infamous Ancestor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His son: R' Akiva.

His infamous ancestor: Sisera.

(See discussion, with sources, in Hyman's Toldos Tannaim V'amoraim, [s.v. R' Akiva](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43958&pgnum=155).)